# Chrome Extension: Can't retrieve values from chrome.local variables

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I am setting `chrome.local` variables in `pop.js` but unable to retrieve them in `content.js`

**popup.js**

```
chrome.storage.local.set('TITLE',title);
```

**content.js**

```
var title = null;
    $(".class").each(function () {
          chrome.storage.local.get('TITLE', function (result) {
                                    title = result.TITLE;
                    console.log('inside'+title);//prints value
                                });


    }

  console.log(title);//returns null;
```

It returns `title` as `null`

Chrome Console outputs as:

```
outside: null
content.js:42 insideJava: A Beginner's Guide, Sixth Edition
```

Comment: Are you sure that the `title` variable has a value in **popup.js**?

Perhaps you could also try `console.log`ing `result`, in **content.js**?

Comment: @BryndenBielefeld I checked it's not even entering in `get` code block. Further explaination added

Comment: It sounds like the problem is coming from elsewhere in your code.

I see you've updated your question. If `title` is declared in **content.js**, I do believe it is out of scope. Where have you defined it?

Comment: I just re-read your comment, you said "it's not even entering the `get` block". Perhaps there aren't any elements on the page that can be selected with the CSS-selector that you provided to jQuery.

Comment: @BryndenBielefeld I am checking further, code is broken before that I guess

Comment: @BryndenBielefeld What actually is happening, the value of `title` is accessed before the `get` block, may be because it's asynchronous. Question updated further. Question updated

Comment: `chrome.storage.local.get` is asynchronous, yes, so you'll need to restructure your code to account for that. If possible, it might be best to do whatever you need to do with `title`, inside the `get` block, rather than trying to do it *after*.

Answer (score 0):

`chrome.storage.local.get` is an asynchronous call, which means when you call `console.log(title);`, callback of `chrome.storage.local.get` has not been executed, then `title` remains `null`. You should put your logic inside the callback.

Comment: _Please_, Haibara. Use canonical duplicates.

Comment: @Xan, Sorry, I did want to flag that, but due to network issue I was not able to find the id. I will do that tomorrow or Monday

Comment: I did already - you should have a handy list of most-used dupes.

Comment: @Xan, gotcha, I used to find the dupe in frequent category..